# Custom API call on Azure Mobile App Service

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I have HTML/JS client trying to access APIController on Azure Mobile App service.

Following is my code

```
var _client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/");

var pp = _client.invokeApi("/Lookup/GetTransactionType", {
    body: null,
    method: "get",
    parameters: { TenantID: 1 },
    headers: {
        "ZUMO-API-VERSION": "2.0.0",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Cache-Control":"false",
        "x-zumo-auth": "tada"
    }
}).done(function (results) {
    var message = results.results.count;
    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.message)
    });
```

The issue here is that my api's are published as such :

> https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/Lookup/GetTransactionType?TenantID={{TenantID}}

But I get NOT FOUND error in client since its looking for following URL :

> (XHR)GET - https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Lookup/GetTransactionType?TenantID=1

How can I eliminate the ***/api*** in the URI?

Comment: it seems that to prevent this behavior you need to call the .invokeApi function with the absolute url of your request: http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/sdk_src_MobileServiceClient.js.html#line404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rolspace mentioned, you need to call the `.invokeApi` function with the absolute URL (must start with `http://` or `https://`) to eliminate the `/api` in the URI.

So you can change the line of code to:

```
var pp = _client.invokeApi(_client.applicationUrl + "/Lookup/GetTransactionType", { //...
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. You have typo in there. Should be *_client.applicationUrl*